# remote php mysql_connect to SQL server set up at home

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

I have set up a free domain online. I have set up an SQL Server 2012 on my home PC.
Question: how can I make it possible for my php MySql_connect to connect to my home SQL server?
Let's say I have a database of my birthday wishes, and anyone who access the website can click the Show button and the list would appear.

Comment: Just because both MySQL and SQL Server have "SQL" in their names it doesn't mean they are the same product.

Comment: You cannot use mysql libraries to connect to SQL server. Not compatible.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: @RobertRozas It is more advised that you use the PDO Api, and instal the needed drivers. mssql_* is apart of `PHP5-Sybase` and PHP is not always built with these functions ( run `phpinfo();` and you will see the flag `--without-mssql`

Comment: That's ok Daril.....download the driver here: http://download.moodle.org/download.php/dblib/php52/DBLIB_TS.zip (PHP 5.2.x (vc6))  or http://download.moodle.org/download.php/dblib/php53/DBLIB_TS.zip (PHP 5.3.x (vc9)) ....just uncoment the extension on php.ini and use it with the PDO extension ;)

Comment: @RobertRozas For safe of mind, please post official download links from PHP.net and not mirrors (unless necessary)

Comment: Ok Daryl, it' s just because i don't find an official link form PHP so i post a mirror....just like you said ;)  ....i just want to help ok

Comment: @RobertRozas Sorry for the delay, the Download link is avilable on the official PHP.net manual -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Comment: That link offer a driver that only works on Windows...the driver i reffer works on both, windows ans linux systems ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server does not use `mysql_*` functions, you will need to use the PDO driver and connect using the SQL Driver.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Then use the PDO Api

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

and to make it external port forward 1433 to your computer via your router.

---

Also, ensure that you have configured your SQL Server for mixed mode authentication (Server/local authentication) and create different user accounts per database. Do not connect to MSSQL Servers via the built-in administrator account (sa)

Answer (score 0):

At home, search "My IP" in Google and it should show you your router's external IP address. This is what you would use as the `host` parameter for `mysql_connect`. Unfortunately, if your router restarts or you lose power, etc., your IP address is likely to change since your ISP hands out IPs dynamically.

If your domain name is coupled with a server that you are able to access, or if your web hosting provider provides you with PHP, you could use phpMyAdmin or something similar to easily set up a database on the server instead. Then you can connect to `localhost`.

There isn't a clear connection between MySQL and SQL Server. SQL Server is a Microsoft product while MySQL is an open-source-now-Oracle product. They probably won't play nicely together. The idea of setting up a database on the server sounds more and more enticing.

Comment: When port forwarding, you need your internal IP address, so run a `ipconfig` via command prompt, then point the port being opened towards your PC

Comment: The dynamic IP problem you mention can be fixed by using services such as [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) and [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/).

Comment: @DarylGill, thanks, I forgot about that part. marco-fiset, that's correct, but those are paid services so it depends what you're willing to spend :)

Comment: @marco-fiset there is no real problem with dynamic IP addressing, I have been on a dynamic IP address for a number of years prior to requesting a static WANIP all is required, is a slight re-configuration of your portforwarding. If you have a router with a DHCP assigining local IP addreses which you find that it changes; then create a DHCP reservation for your computer, so your internal IP address will always remain the same

Comment: @DarylGill I was talking about the external IP address which can change because `ISP hands out IPs dynamically`.

Comment: @marco-fiset again, you will have to perform minor configuration changes if you do not use no-ip for example, or if using no-ip, i'm sure there might need to be a re-configuration somewhere along the lines (just assumptions because i've never seen the point in DNS services)

Comment: @DarylGill Hosting an application on your home server is looking for trouble because of the dynamic nature of your external IP address. That's where dynamic DNS services come in handy. Plus many ISPs will block key ports (like port 80 for http) which will make it impossible for you to host a web app at home for example. A dynamic DNS service will handle the port redirection for you and will ensure that whatever your external IP is, your server will get the request. I understand that you must have a fixed internal IP and port forwarding enabled, but that's not what I was referring to.